# How to intersect more than 2 polygons using Turf.js?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, turf

We use Mapbox GL JS 1.12.0 in our Vue.js project. I need to create intersection objects if I have 2 or more polygons. But, I'm able to do it with 2 polygons only. The code looks as following:

```
import * as turf from '@turf/turf';

export function createIntersection(features) {
  // features = 3 polygons on the screen bellow
  const intersection = turf.intersect(...features);

  return intersection;
}
```

The screenshots:

1. Unselected polygons:

[image]

2. Selected polygons

[image]

3. After code execution

[image]

As you can see there is only 1 intersection object created.

How to do it with more than 2 polygons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use turf-intersect https://github.com/Turfjs/turf-intersect then the only option is to compute the intersections by comparing the geometries one by one (1 to 2, 1 to 3, 2 to 3) because there must be exactly two single part polygons as input.

With @turf/intersect https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/tree/master/packages/turf-intersect you could first build a multipolygon from the two not-intersecting polygons, if you know what they are, and then get the intersection with the third geometry by one intersect operation ((1 + 2) against 3). Even in this case there must be exactly two inputs but they may be either polygons or multipolygons. The result is also a single geometry that in this case would be a multipolygon with two parts.